# Large list of backlinks disappear from Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console

I typically have 700-800 backlinks listed in GSC. I normally check this list every other week.  However, today when I checked, it showed 73.  At first I suspected that Google cleaned up all of the garbage backlinks.  That doesn't seem to be the case.  Then I thought, maybe Google is only showing backlinks in the recent past.  However, the current list is showing some links that are several years old and the same percentage of garbage backlinks.

Did Google change their interface or their algorithm?

Comment: Quite a few people are reporting the sudden loss of links in that report.